# html minify script creates issues with <script>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

hi i have a php script for minify the page without never comment or space , this is my script:

```
<?php

function sanitize_output($buffer) {

    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  
        '/(\s)+/s'       
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

ob_start("sanitize_output");

?>
```

but have a problem with the comment in the inline  tag `<script>`

example if have :

```
<script>
$('#table22').stack({myClass:'small-only'}); // this is a comment
</script>
```

load the page with trouble and jquery / js not working.(if erase the comment work fine)

how can  solve this problem ?? or in alternative exclude tag `<script>` from this script.

Comment: Turn on HTTP compression; forget about this 'sanitization'. Anyway, please include the *actual* HTML that PHP generates for the shown script as that should make the problem .. obvious.

Comment: @user2864740 can you clarify ?

Comment: What is the *actual* HTML that "doesn't work"? You'll see that it ends up like `<script>some script // comment more script hiding behind the comment</script>` - which should make the problem clear. My recommendation is to leave the HTML content alone, but to [enable HTTP compression](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/), which is *very* good at this sort of thing. HTTP compression will have a much larger overall impact on decreasing the response size and does not require a content-altering and brittle approach used that caused the problem.

Comment: this whole `sanitize_output()` thing threw me off...so you're not attempting to sanitize *user input* but rather to compress your page? You should make that more clear.

Comment: @user2864740 yes but the problem it's clear, the problem is how solve, my script work fine for html , but for comment in script not work, i see in autput code this script cut part of script

Comment: @ developerwjk   i want minify the output code of page. , never comment , never space.

Comment: i would exclude anything inside `<script>` there is a number of ways to break JavaScript with this. Of course i wouldn't bother at all and just send compressed output from the server which will be smaller than this makes.

Comment: You might also want to look at the console errors to see if it helps you identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try commenting with `/* this is a comment */` instead of `// this is a comment` as when the lines are compressed the comment may well be marking the rest of the file as a comment and thus breaking the javascript.